Jenkins - master slave
I have a jenkins master running in windows operating system and have another PC with ubuntu,i want to setup a master agent connection in jenkins,I established the node connection using the file agent.jar and the node is in online,but when i try to run one pipeline where the first step is cloning the git repo the pipeline fails with the error.
Error Details:
No credentials specified
Cloning the remote Git repository
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not init /home/agent1/jenkins/agent/workspace/git-clone-check

the git is installed properly and manually. I am able to clone from the ubuntu device. How to resolve this issue ?
